# jquery contextMenu hide/show event not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, contextmenu

My show and hide events are not triggered unless I place an alert() inside the method or I have a breakpoint in Chrome Developer Tools inside the function.

I do not want an alert to show.  What could I be missing?
Thanks!

Here is my JQuery contextMenu object (with alert functions):

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: 'circle',
            trigger: 'left',
            events: {
                show: function(options) {
                    contextMenuIsOpen = true;
                    if ($("#GraphType option:selected").text() == "Line")
                        chart = "#chart";

                    $(chart).data("kendoChart").options.tooltip.visible = false;
                    alert("Show Context Menu");
                },
                hide: function (options) {
                    contextMenuIsOpen = false;
                    $(chart).data("kendo-chart").options.tooltip.visible = true;
                    alert("Hide Context Menu");
                }
            },
            build: function () {
                return buildMenu();
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What information are you needing?  That link does not help me nor you since I don't know what else I need to add to a make my question make more sense.

Comment: Is this wrapped inside a load callback (`$.ready()` or `$()` ...) or not?

Comment: If you are seeing those alerts, then those functions are almost certainly still triggering when you take them out. Why do you think they are not? Have you checked the console for errors, breakpointed and stepped over the code to check it is working as expected? You simply need to do some more debugging to determine what the issue really is. The code provided in your question is not enough for us to recreate the problem so it is difficult to help you (which I believe Chris G was alluding to in his comment).

Comment: Exactly. Put together a jsfiddle or add a working example to your question. As it is now, we can only guess what the problem is. The alarms are both at the end of the functions so the fact that they appear would point to the functions being run. Like @NigelK said, do some basic troubleshooting. For starters, replace the `alert()`  calls with `console.log()` Does it still work?

Comment: Actually, one way the alarms might "fix" the code is if somehow both `show` and `hide` get triggered and run in sequence. Without the alarms, the `show` change is immediately reversed by `hide`; but since the alarms block the script, it "works" if you have them in there.

Comment: I replaced the alerts with console.log and they were both triggered.
I then noticed something really interesting. If I moved my mouse off of the kendo chart after triggering the context menu, the `$(chart).data("kendoChart").options.tooltip.visible = false` then worked and my tooltip events would no longer be triggered while I was navigating the context menu.  However, if I kept my mouse on the chart with the context menu up, the tooltip hover events continued to be triggered.

I cannot make a JSFiddle because the code contains business information.

Comment: The "Hide Context Menu" log did not show until I clicked away, so it's not being triggered right after the "show" event.

Comment: I have debugged through it and I can't replicate the problem because while I'm debugging my mouse moves away from the chart and the problem goes away. I could not step through and find an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ChrisG, ibrahim mahrir and NigelK suggestions, I was able to figure out that this was not a jQuery contextMenu issue but a kendo chart issue.

Instead of using `$(chart).data("kendo-chart").options.tooltip.visible` to set the tooltip visibility to true or false, I am instead using `$(chart).data("kendo-chart").setOptions({ tooltip: { visible: false } } );`

I hope this answer can help anyone who comes across this issue themselves.

Thank you so much for your help.  StackOverflow has the best people!